# Do I really need SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True

Tags: python, django, session

Context: In my template, I click "Add product" and it takes me to another template where I have a list of all the products, I choose one and  it takes me back to my selected product list template, and I keep adding so on.

In my receiver view I have this:

```
def vw_Sell(request):
    if request.POST:
    POST_received = request.POST

    if 'ses_productList' in request.session:
        request.session['ses_productList'].append({
            'product': POST_received['idProduct'],
            'quant': POST_received['quantity'],
        })
    else:
        request.session['ses_productList'] = []

    producList = request.session['ses_productList']
else:
    if 'ses_productList' in request.session:
        producList = request.session['ses_productList']
    else:
        producList = {}

context = {
    "selected_products": producList
}

return render(request, "shop.html", context)
```

It only saves the first product to the session dictionary. I researched and found the `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST` and set it to True, and then it works, but I'm worry if I'm doing the correct way, thanks!

Comment: Where exactly is that code? Can you post the view code?

Comment: Thankyou, I just edited the code in the post.

What I really need to know is whether I actually need to set true the SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST or there is another way to make the session dictionary save every time I make an append to the dictionary in my List.

Answer (score 2):

The session will only be saved automatically, if its `modified` property is `True`. That property is set every time you call the session object's `__setitem__()` method (usually via the `=` operator).

Here is the [Django code for it](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py#L45).

However, you are appending to an *already existing* list, so the session object never knows that anything changed. To save the session, you need to set its `modified` property manually

```
request.session.modified = True
```

to mark the session "dirty" and have the session's Middleware save it.

The [session Middleware code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py#L20).

Answer (score 0):

Final code thanks to @C14L:

```
if 'ses_productList' in request.session:
        request.session['ses_productList'].append({
            'product': POST_received['idProduct'],
            'quant': POST_received['quantity'],
        })
request.session.modified = True
```